# .each function () for cloned inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to create the Preview form and do not understand why each function () not working in this script. Or works but only for the last cloned row and ignore the zero values ​​in the previously cloned inputs.

```
$('input[id^=Mult_factor_]').each(function () {
    var MultFactor = $(this).val();
    var TotPoints = $('#Tot_points').val();
    var exp1 = "Overload";
    var exp2 = "Load is: ";
    if (MultFactor < 1 || TotPoints > 100) {
        $('#ExemptionLimitsText').text(exp1).show();
        $('#PrwTotPointsText').hide();
    } else {
        $('#ExemptionLimitsText').text(exp2).show();
        $('#PrwTotPointsText').text($('#Tot_points').val()).show();
    }
});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BE5Lr/3889/)

I need: If at least one of cloned MultiFactor value is zero show "Overload"
[image]

Comment: Don't understand what you are trying to do... Copy "Mult_factor_" in a preview form?

Comment: can you explain bit more about what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I`am trying to test your code in JSFiddle 
every time I click on preview button   result is overload

Comment: If MultFaktor value on first row is zero and MultFaktor on second row is greater than zero show "Overload". If at least one of cloned Multifactor value is zero show "Overload"

Comment: well you should return false on overload

Comment: @Wilmer Return false on overload and this works fine. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you want to display the word "Overload" if either the "Additional" field is over 100 or if any of the multifactor fields is 0.

However, your loop continues to process if either of these conditions are met.

Do not use a loop, instead search specifically for a multifaktor value of 0.

```
var totalPoints = parseInt($('#Tot_points').val());
if(totalPoints > 100 || $('input[name="MultFaktor"]').filter(function(){return this.value=='0'}).length > 0) {
    $('#ExemptionLimitsText').text("Overload").show();
    $('#PrwTotPointsText').hide();
} else {
    $('#ExemptionLimitsText').text("Load is: ").show();
    $('#PrwTotPointsText').text(totalPoints).show();
}
```

Comment: A benefit of this is that it won't even bother looking for MultFaktor values of 0 if total points is over 100.

Answer (score 0):

Return false on overload

```
var valid = true;
var exp1 = "Overload";
var exp2 = "Load is: ";
var TotPoints = $('#Tot_points').val();

$('input[name=MultFaktor]').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '0' || TotPoints > 100) {
        valid = false;
    } else {
        $('#ExemptionLimitsText').text(exp2).show();
        $('#PrwTotPointsText').text($('#Tot_points').val()).show();
    }
});

if (valid == false) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#ExemptionLimitsText').text(exp1).show();
    $('#PrwTotPointsText').hide();
}
```